# Can't assign value using $this in class

Tags: php, class

I have class like this

```html
Class something{
    public $token;

    public function nameA()
    {
        $this->token = 'value';
    }
    public function nameB(){
        echo $this->token;
    }
}

$ok = new something();
$ok->nameB();
```

why i get nothing when using $ok->nameB();?

Comment: Because `new something();` won't automagically run `nameA()` for you; and unless you call `nameA()` then the `token` property has a null value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to use the natural constructor method in the class then your code would be ok

```
Class something{
    public $token;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->token = 'value';
    }
    public function nameB(){
        echo $this->token;
    }
}

$ok = new something();
$ok->nameB();
```

Comment: it's work, but is it any other way i can insert the value other than using __construnt() ?

Comment: With your code you would need to call `nameA()` first

Comment: Technically they've set `token` to be a public class member anyway - you can just manipulate it through `$ok->token = "fred"; echo $ok->token; //prints "fred"` The class isn't encapsulated in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `nameA()` before to assign a value, here the token is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The property `$token` is null until given a value.

In your class, the only way this can happen is if the `nameA` method is called, or you directly manipulate the property, so you would need to do that first:

```
Class something{
    public $token;

    public function nameA()
    {
        $this->token = 'value';
    }
    public function nameB(){
        echo $this->token;
    }
}

$ok = new something();
$ok->nameA(); //<--sets property
//or direct manipulation: $ok->token = 'blah';
$ok->nameB(); //<-- reads and outputs it
```

An alternative would be to set the property in the constructor:

```
Class something{
    public $token;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->token = 'value';
    }
    public function nameB(){
        echo $this->token;
    }
}

$ok = new something(); //<-- sets propery
$ok->nameB(); //<--reads and outputs it
```

Or you could initialize the propery with a value:

```
Class something{
    public $token = 'default';

    public function nameA()
    {
        $this->token = 'value';
    }
    public function nameB(){
        echo $this->token;
    }
}

$ok = new something();
$ok->nameB(); //outputs 'default'
$ok->nameA(); //sets to 'value'
$ok->nameB(); //outputs 'value'
```

Comment: Nice answer - fallen foul of the SO "fastest finger first" effect though...